# libcurl use 1 connection for multiple concurrent requests

Tags: c, libcurl

I would like to use 1 CURL handle and do let's say 10 concurrent requests with this handle. Would that be possible? The problem is if I want for example 100 concurrent requests it opens too many connections and sometimes server refuses to answer because too many connections are already opened from the same IP. But if I had one handle and use this handle for many requests in multiple threads that would probably solve the problem. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: Add pseudo code for cURL functioned used in thread. Refer https://linux.die.net/man/3/curl_easy_duphandle

Comment: @Pravin the question is rather obvious, I don't see a reason to add any code. The duphandle is wrong: "The new handle will not inherit any state information, no connections, no SSL sessions and no cookies."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to do multiple requests *in parallel* on the same single connection, you need to use HTTP/2 and all those requests have to be made to the same host. That's an usual situation though. You then need to ask libcurl to use HTTP/2 and you need to use the multi interface. Like in the [http2-download.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http2-download.html) example.

If you have multiple URLs to different hosts and want to limit the number of connections used to transfer those, you can use the easy interface and get the URLs one by one to keep down the number of used connections - in combination with [CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS.html).

If you want to use the multi interface, you can still allow libcurl to do a limited amount of parallel transfers with [CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS.html) and friends, even if you add a hundred easy handles at once. Or you can just limit the number of concurrently added easy handles.